# Cannot connect psql from host machine to postgresql on docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I'm follow up with [this repo](https://github.com/brocoders/nestjs-boilerplate) and try to connect psql from my local machine to Postgresql on docker image after running `docker compose up -d` but I got this error
[image]

I tried with `adminer` portal that come along with repo and it **can be connected successfully** with service name `postgres` and the same credentials
[image]

- I guess port mapping is good, here is the result from `docker container ls`
  [image]
- tried to use `127.0.0.1` or `postgres` instead of `localhost` but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The default user in pg db is postgres (not root).

Try `postgres` as username

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't change anything in the [`env-example` or `.env` files](https://github.com/brocoders/nestjs-boilerplate/blob/main/env-example#L10C6-L15), you should be able to authenticate with the following values:

```
System: PostgreSQL
Server: postgres
Username: root
Password: secret
Database: api
```

Here is a [video showing a successful login](https://www.loom.com/share/b2bd103778d540d7b5799b4f18820b50).